# Why my React Query does not instant update UI after delete?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

The deleted Todo item is still on display after clicking the delete button.

It does not immediately remove on display, but on my db.json file it shows that it has been deleted.

I also test by placing the component inside App.jsx and there was no problem everything works fine but when I nested the component the delete function works yet it does not immediately update

I'm using
json-server,
react vite,
react query

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, useMutation, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

export const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8500",
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const SingleTask = ({ listId }) => {
  const { data: taskTodo } = useQuery(
    ["tasks", listId],
    async () => (await axiosClient.get(`/tasks/${listId}/subtasks`)).data,
    {
      initialData: [],
    }
  );

  const deleteTask = useMutation(
    ({id}) => axiosClient.delete(`/subtasks/${id}`),
    {
      onSettled: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(["tasks"])
    }
  );

  return (
    <>
      {taskTodo
        ?.filter((entry) => entry.status != true)
        .map((list) => (
          <React.Fragment key={list.id}>
            <div className="mt-6">
              <div className="flex justify-between items-center text-sm">
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                  <p>{list.title}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-4">
                  <button onClick={() => {
                    deleteTask.mutate(list);
                  }}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default SingleTask;
```

Here is the json data of tasks and subtask

json data

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": false,
      "title": "List One",
      "details": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "status": false,
      "title": "List Two",
      "details": ""
    }
  ],
  "subtasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "taskId": 1,
      "status": false,
      "title": "Subtask for list one",
      "details": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "taskId": 2,
      "status": true,
      "title": "Subtask for list two",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're invalidating your query. After the query gets invalidated, it will do a refetch of your active query (that is `["tasks", listId]`, [unless you specify otherwise](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries)). So you have to wait for the refetch to complete in order to see the update, thus it is not immediate.

If you want it to be "immediate" and if you know what the state will look like, you can use [optimistic updates](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/optimistic-updates) for that.

In your case it could be something like this:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

useMutation(({id}) => axiosClient.delete(`/subtasks/${id}`), {
  // When mutate is called:
  onMutate: async ({id}) => {
    // Cancel any outgoing refetches (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
    await queryClient.cancelQueries(['tasks', id])

    // Snapshot the previous value
    const previousTasks = queryClient.getQueryData(['tasks', id])

    // Optimistically update to the new value
    queryClient.setQueryData(['tasks', id], old => old.filter((t) => t.id !== id))

    // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
    return { previousTasks }
  },
  // If the mutation fails, use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
  onError: (err, { id }, context) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['tasks', id], context.previousTasks)
  },
  // Always refetch after error or success:
  onSettled: (newData, error, { id }) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['tasks', id])
  },
})
```

**UPDATE**

Since your query keys are dependant on `list.listId`s and not `list.id`s (like I assumed), you would need to update your `useMutation` function to something like this:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

useMutation(({ id }) => axiosClient.delete(`/subtasks/${id}`), {
  onMutate: async ({ listId, id }) => {
    await queryClient.cancelQueries(['tasks', listId]);

    const previousTasks = queryClient.getQueryData(['tasks', listId]);

    queryClient.setQueryData(['tasks', listId], (old) => old.filter((t) => t.id !== id));

    return { previousTasks };
  },
  onError: (err, { listId }, context) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['tasks', listId], context.previousTasks);
  },
  onSettled: (newData, error, { listId }) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['tasks', listId]);
  },
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') after clicking the delete button

Comment: You shouldn't c/p my code and expect for it to work. I just gave you an example of how it could potentially look like. You have to adjust your own implementation to work with optimistic updates. Read the docs about optimistic updates carefully and try to understand it, then you will be able to adapt it to your specific example.

Comment: Yup I did not immediately c/p your sample code, I tried to adjust it on my own implementation. Then it successfully deleted a single task but I still get the same effect, it did not immediately re-fetch. BTW this single component is nested, here's my nesting structure App.jsx -> Tasklist.jsx -> Singletask.jsx

Comment: Try using `old?.filter` instead of `old.filter`, that way you won't get the error, but it still won't work probably, because the `old` data has to be defined. The query key you use in `useQuery`, `["tasks", listId]` has to be the same one you use in `queryClient.setQueryData(['tasks', id], old => old.filter((t) => t.id !== id))`. Make sure that the `id` is not `undefined` and make sure that the `listId` you use in `useQuery` is equal to `id` you use in `queryClient.setQueryData`.

Comment: I might be using it wrong because the `listId` in useQuery is the `id` of the list group, while the `id` used in `queryClient.setQueryData` is the `id` of a single `task`.

Comment: What does your `list` object look like? The one you're passing to the `mutate` function here: `deleteTask.mutate(list)`? Does it maybe have a `listId` property? If it does have that prop, then in your `onMutate: async ({id}) => { ...` function instead of `({id})` use that `listId`. Maybe something like `onMutate: async ({listId}) => { ...`. And also replace the `id` throughout your `onMutate` function with `listId`.

Comment: I'll add the object above

Comment: @BJ2Zbj I have updated my answer, see if that will solve your problem